# Parsing XML data into string objects using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I have to parse a xml into string objects in JAXB. But how to creates objects for this xml

Country.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <Country>       
        <name>India</name>
        <capital>New Delhi</capital>
        <population>120crores</population>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

<states>
    <state>
        <name>Maharastra</name>
        <pincode>xyzzzz</pincode>
        <capital>Mumbai</capital>

    <\state>

    <state>
    .
    .
    .
    </state>
</states>


   <\Country>
```

And to parse this xml I have created class to map the objects which creates the objects and print it in the console. But Don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Country")
    public void setCountry(String Countryv) {
        Country= Countryv;
    }

@XmlElement (name = "name")
    public void setname(String namev) {
        name= namev;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "capital")
    public void setcapital(String capitalv) {
        capital= capitalv;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "population")
    public void setpopulation(String populationv) {
        population= populationv;
    }


    @XmlElementWrapper(name="states")
    public void setType(String statesv) {
        states = statesv;
    }



@XmlElementWrapper(name="state")
        public void setType(String statev) {
            state = statev;
        }




    @XmlElement (name = "name")
        public void setpopulation(String namev) {
            name= namev;
        }

     @XmlElement (name = "pincode")
        public void setpopulation(String pincodev) {
            pincode= pincodev;
        }

 @XmlElement (name = "capital")
        public void setpopulation(String capitalv) {
            capital= capitalv;
        }
```

when I run the program I m getting the

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 
>   counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

How to add wrapper anotations to wrapping the elements under separate headers and headers inside other headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "capital",
    "population",
    "states"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Country")
public class Country {
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String capital;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String population;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected Country.States states;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
    public void setCapital(String value) {
        this.capital = value;
    }
    public String getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    public void setPopulation(String value) {
        this.population = value;
    }
    public Country.States getStates() {
        return states;
    }
    public void setStates(Country.States value) {
        this.states = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked  for me

```
class Country {
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    //...
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="states")
    List<State> state;
}

class State {
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    //..
}
```